# Attendances query which has different DATE between DATE IN and DATE OUT

Tags: mysql, sql

We have little problem with querying fingerprint logs for attendances system.

Our sample data looks like this :

TABLE FINGER_LOGS :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| ID | FINGER_ID | DATETIME       |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  | IT         | 2015-12-01 09:00
| 2  | IT         | 2015-12-01 16:30
| 3  | GA         | 2015-12-01 09:30
| 4  | GA         | 2015-12-01 17:00
| 5  | SECURITY   | 2015-12-01 08:00
| 6  | SECURITY   | 2015-12-01 19:00
| 7  | SECURITY2  | 2015-12-01 19:00
| 8  | SECURITy2  | 2015-12-02 07:00
```

We have to change the format of TABLE FINGER_LOGS to :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| FINGER_ID | DATE       | IN    | OUT |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| IT        | 2015-12-01 | 09:00 | 16:30
| GA        | 2015-12-01 | 09:00 | 17:00
| SECURITY  | 2015-12-01 | 08:00 | 19:00
| SECURITy2 | 2015-12-01 | 19:00 | 07:00    
| SECURITy2 | 2015-12-02 | 19:00 | 07:00
```

We have tried with this query :

```
SELECT 
    i.FINGER_ID, i.DATE, i.TIME_IN, o.TIME_OUT
FROM
    (SELECT 
        i.FINGER_ID,
        min(cast(i.DATE as date)) as 'DATE',
        DATE(DATE_ADD(i.DATE, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)) as 'TOMMOROW',     
        min(cast(i.DATE as time)) as 'TIME_IN'
    FROM
        FINGER_LOGS as i
    GROUP BY i.FINGER_ID , cast(i.DATE as date)) as i
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        o.FINGER_ID,
            max(cast(o.DATE as date)) as 'DATE',
            max(cast(o.DATE as time)) as 'TIME_OUT'
    FROM
        FINGER_LOGS as o
    GROUP BY o.FINGER_ID , cast(o.DATE as date), DATE(DATE_ADD(o.DATE, INTERVAL - 1 DAY))

    ) as o ON i.FINGER_ID = o.FINGER_ID
        AND (i.DATE = o.DATE
        OR o.DATE = i.TOMMOROW)
```

But the result is :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| FINGER_ID | DATE       | IN    | OUT |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| IT        | 2015-12-01 | 09:00 | 16:30
| GA        | 2015-12-01 | 09:00 | 17:00
| SECURITY  | 2015-12-01 | 08:00 | 19:00
| SECURITy2 | 2015-12-01 | 19:00 | 19:00    
| SECURITy2 | 2015-12-01 | 19:00 | 07:00
| SECURITy2 | 2015-12-02 | 07:00 | 07:00
```

The source of problems is between DATE IN & OUT of SECURITy2 which has different DATE (+1 day from DATE IN)

If you have a solution for this problems please let us know,

Thanks for your help and assistance :)

---

This is required format from vendor, i got from email :

```
....
Our Format :

Database Server  = MySQL
DBName           = ixfinger
Tablename        = fingerlog
Fields :
    Finger_id     autoincrement_primarkey                            
    fingerid      varchar(252) ID from fingerprint
    tdate         date
    timein        time
    timeout       time
    transferred   tinyint (fill with 0)
....
```

---

Comment: Your desired output doesn't really make sense.  Why would you have an `out` time of `07:00` on the same day, when that is not accurate.

Comment: Date must be specified for dates in and out, because like your data, the security date out the next day, that's why the date is also needed for the timeout.

Comment: What is the purpose of the join? Why do you need to match different rows of the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff , john Pangilinan and Barmar This format required by application vendor of our company which the "best" one, they make us to make small application for import data from our fingerprint machine so we have to convert FINGER_LOGS (default format from fingerprint machine) to there format

And I can't change theres format... or just add 1 more field for date in / out

Comment: Please describe expected database formats from application vendor. Currently you're showing sample data but it's already one step downstream and may be flawed; I would like to see the expected DDL.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing which entry is 'IN' and which entry is 'OUT'? Or do you just expect the first entry for an ID to be 'IN', the second 'OUT', etc.?

In that case, how is clean-up managed?

Comment: @Sebas i have only one access to vendor's table and i added "required format from vendor" in question

Comment: can OUT be null ( if they leave through a side door )

Comment: Yeah you could generate 1 record per day, with either in or out or both null depending on what happened that day. The other possibility is to use the fact that the TIME type is not limited to 24 hours